# How can this question be Off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just came across [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44369/should-i-quit-a-maternity-leave-contract-before-ends-b-c-im-being-treated-in-an) and found that it was put on hold as off topic. But, to me question looks genuine and OP is really asking for help. Question is surely related to workplace and OP is not the only person on earth who has faced this issue and certainly (unfortunately :( ) many more people will face similar situations in future so in that sense question will be useful for future visitors also.

Won't you think community should be allowed to answer this question and help the OP ? I am sure many good answers will eventually come for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is off topic because the question of "should I quit" is very specific to the person, and we have no idea who that person is.

While "should I quit?" questions can be interesting to read, and can lead to interesting responses, they generally don't translate into being useable to other people who are also asking "should I quit?". Everybodys situation is different and their ability to find another job is also different.

In the case of the specific question it isn't even a very difficult question to answer:

- in x months the original replacement will be back, and they will need to find a job anyway.
- Since they have no desire to try and remain an employee with the company they should start looking now.
- If they find a new job, and they understand what penalties they face regarding leaving early, then they either leave early or give a starting date after the end of the temp contract.

Comment: thanks, that clears everything.